# How to generate, sign and distribute passbook passes via email with Grails?

Tags: grails, ios6, passbook

Are there any good plugins, tutorials, etc., that walk through this?

Comment: Grails and iOS 6 aren't really typically used together, so it's doubtful.

Comment: Ken, this is not to run on iOS 6.  It is to create passes server side and send them via email.

Answer (score 3):

I recommend [jpasskit](https://github.com/bitzeche/jpasskit). Here is some example code for creating the pass:

```
PKPass pass = new PKPass()
// add information to the pass

def certFile = getCertificatePath() + File.separator + P12_CERT_NAME
def wwdrca = getCertificatePath() + File.separator + APPLE_WWDRCA_NAME
def tempDir = createTempDir()

PKSigningInformation pkSigningInformation = PKSigningUtil.loadSigningInformationFromPKCS12FileAndIntermediateCertificateFile(
        certFile,
        PASSBOOK_SIGNING_PASSWORD,
        wwdrca)
byte[] passZipBytes = PKSigningUtil.createSignedAndZippedPkPassArchive(pass, tempDir.absolutePath, pkSigningInformation)
```

You might want to follow the [Apple guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/PassKit_PG/Chapters/YourFirst.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012195-CH2-SW1) for some of the above as @Fabiano noted. Then to attach your passes to an email, you could use the [Mail plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/mail):

```
List myPasses = getPasses() // using code from above, plus adding unique names to passes
def contentType = "application/vnd.apple.pkpass"
mailService.sendMail {
            multipart true
            getMessage().setTo(emailAddresses as String[])
            from(mailFromAddress)
            subject(subjectString)
            body(view: bodyTemplate, model: model)
            myPasses.each {
                attachBytes(it.name, contentType, it.bytes)
            }
        }
```

Where it.bytes refers to passZipBytes and it.name is the unique name of the pass, such as a barcode number. You will need to fill in some gaps here or there, but that's the basis of how to do it.

There is a bouncycastle dependency issue between Grails 2.x and jpasskit-0.0.2. Get them to play nice:

```
inherits("global") {
    ...
    excludes 'bcprov-jdk15', 'bcpg-jdk15'
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

We have recently done it our grails project [LIKELLA.com](http://likella.com)

A free 'Do-It-Yourself' Loyalty platform.

Simply follow the [apple guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/PassKit_PG/Chapters/YourFirst.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012195-CH2-SW1).

For signing in grails we have used [bouncy castle library](http://www.bouncycastle.org/)

A guide for signing with bouncy caste in PKCS7 can be found [here](http://i-proving.com/2007/09/21/pkcs7-signatures-using-bouncy-castle/), it's not updated to the last bouncy castle version but is a good starting point.

If you more help we can even offer commercial support at info at likella dot com.

Comment: Thanks for the library recommendation

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to sign it without using BouncyCastle, then take a look at this question:

https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/13910/pkcs7-encoding-in-java-without-external-libs-like-bouncycastle-etc

I'm actually going to use this approach for signing the content.